# Android-change cardview background color parsing json

Tags: android, json, background-color

> I am trying to set background color of the cardview parsing json. I
>   have provided hex-code in my database. I am pulling hex-color code json in my android. If there is any other way to provide color codes in my database please suggest me. It would be great if u provide my code snippet. Here is my android adapter code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import java.util.List;

public class categories_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    List<categories_data> data;
    String catid;

    public categories_adapter(Context context, List<categories_data> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_layout,parent,false);
        Myholder holder = new Myholder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        com.x.card.categories_list.categories_adapter.Myholder myholder = (com.x.card.categories_list.categories_adapter.Myholder) holder;
        categories_data current = data.get(position);
        myholder.tv.setText(current.categ_name);
      myholder.catcard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(current.catcol));
        Glide.with(context).load(current.cat_image).into(myholder.imv);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class Myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView imv;
        TextView tv;
        CardView catcard;

        public Myholder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cimv);
            tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_name);
            linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linlay);
            catcard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.catcard);

            linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    categories_data currentItem = data.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    Intent i = new Intent(context,products.class);
                    i.putExtra("catid",currentItem.catid);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                }

            });

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello Praveen you should provide some code if you want some help.

Comment: There u go I provided the code of my adapter class

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: I want to set background color of the card fetching json. I am providing hex color codes in the database

Comment: Ok. So you first need create a model that represent the json response, then parse the response from the server and pass it to the recycler view and then use the color parsed from the json.

Answer (score 0):

Octal and hexadecimal formats are not used in JSON. You can try storing decimal numbers in database and convert it to hex after parsing. Otherwise you can use rgb.